# How to remove a permission from an apk file?

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo

I want to remove '`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`' from permissions. I created my `apk` file by expo-Reactnative. so I don't have access to android project directly. Now answering to one of these questions would help me alot.

1. How do I remove a permission from a raw-apk file?
2. How can I remove '`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`' permission from an expo project without detaching it?

here's my `app.json` file from expo project:

```
{
"expo": {
"name": "hipotrip",
"description": "This project is really great.",
"slug": "hipotrip",
"privacy": "public",
"sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
"platforms": ["ios", "android"],
"version": "1.0.3",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"scheme": "hipotrip",
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/splash.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"updates": {
  "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "**/*"
],
"ios": {
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.berjistrip.flight",
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "buildNumber": "285"
},
"android": {
  "package": "com.hamitrip.trip360",
  "versionCode":285,
  "permissions": [
    "WRITE_CALENDAR",
    "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "READ_PHONE_STATE",
    "USE_FINGERPRINT",
    "VIBRATE",
    "WAKE_LOCK",
    "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT",
    "com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT",
    "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE",
    "com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION",
    "com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES",
    "com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS",
    "com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT",
    "com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE",
    "com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ",
    "com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE",
    "com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You don't.  You take it away from the manifest.  Correctly removing it from a compiled APK would be difficult.  Also, RN does use that permission, in order to draw error screens.

Comment: @GabeSechan sorry i didn't realize what you said. I'm using expo , so i don't have access to android folder directly.  when i'm getting an apk output file, it includes that permission. reactNative and expo need that for debugging mode. but i don't know how to remove it before getting output.

Comment: First question - you can't.

Comment: I have same problem did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is decompile your APK using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), remove the permission from the manifest, increase the `versionCode`, optionally change the `versionName` as well, then recompile it still using apktool.

You will still need the original keystore that was used to [sign the APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#signing-manually) if you want to be able to upload it again to the Play Store though.

Comment: thank you. it does work. i check this as the correct answer. but if it was possible to do this by expo itself it would be so much easier.